# Am I using Core Location correctly? It doesn't seem to be working

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I just started doing some research into Core Location and it seems that the tutorials that I am following are not working for me. Even when I download the source code and run it, nothing happens. At present I have attempted [this tutorial](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/). When I run it, I get a popup asking if I want iPhone to use my current location. I press ok, and then nothing happens. Am I supposed to do anything else?

I am also using VMWare, and currently am unsure if this is the cause (although my internet connection works perfectly on it). I'm using base sdk ios 4.3 - running simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for location to work, you need to be running the code on an actual device. The latest public iOS SDKs don't yet support location changes in the simulator. The simulator will always return `1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA` (Apple's headquarters) as the location.

See [the Core Location documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497) for more information on using location in your apps. (Although I can't find a citation for the limitation of the simulator at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation within the simulator is always going to return 1, Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA, although Xcode 4.1 and iOS 5 have improved support for testing CoreLocation capabilities in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

iOS5 iPhone simulator supports location simulation.

If you are using 4.3, it does support location in some conditions. I notice that when I am tethering using my iPhone, my iPhone simulator is able to get location from my phone. I can see location update in my simulator when I'm working while commuting in a train. But this update is only through core location. Map gives u Cupertino unless u use iOS5